# Show that if $n \in N$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{ Z}$ s.t. $a+b=n$, then $\overline{a}, \overline{b}$ are additive inverses in $\mathbb{ Z_n}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

If $a+b=n$, then in modulo remainder class have $\overline{a} + \overline{b}= 0$.
So, $\overline{a} = -\overline{b}$.
Hence, proved.

Is it this simple, or am missing something?

Comment: Yes. It is simple.

Comment: You cannot expect anyone to respond in 20 minutes. This site is not working at that fast a pace.